# Mass-add an object if it is an instance of a class

Tags: scala

```
if(script.isInstanceOf[MouseListener])
    canvas.addMouseListener(script.asInstanceOf[MouseListener])
if(script.isInstanceOf[MouseMotionListener])
    canvas.addMouseMotionListener(script.asInstanceOf[MouseMotionListener])
if(script.isInstanceOf[KeyListener])
    canvas.addKeyListener(script.asInstanceOf[KeyListener])
if(script.isInstanceOf[PaintListener])
    addPaint(script.asInstanceOf[PaintListener])
```

This feels very repetitive. Is there a better way to write it?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Can pattern matching match any combination of traits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pattern matching, as Archeg mentions, is already much better. But for this case you might also consider reflection:

```
def addListeners(target: AnyRef, listener: AnyRef, listenerClasses: Class[_]*) = {
  val targetClass = target.getClass
  listenerClasses.foreach { clazz =>
    if (clazz.isInstance(listener)) {
      try {
        val m = targetClass.getMethod("add" + clazz.getSimpleName, clazz)
        m.invoke(target, listener)
      } catch {
        case e => // log exception
      }
    }
  }
}

addListeners(canvas, script, 
  classOf[MouseListener], classOf[MouseMotionListener], classOf[KeyListener], ...)
```

or use [`Class.getInterfaces.filter(_.getName.endsWith("Listener"))`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces%28%29) to avoid enumerating the listener interfaces (you would need some extra logic if you also want to handle interfaces inherited from a superclass).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably *more* repetitive than what you started with, but it doesn't have any casts, and it puts each snippet of Listener-specific code in the appropriate Listener trait:

```
  trait Listener {
    protected def howToAddToCanvas: Seq[Function1[Canvas, Unit]] = Seq.empty

    def addToCanvas(canvas: Canvas): Unit = howToAddToCanvas.forall(_(canvas))
  }

  trait MouseListener extends Listener {
    override def howToAddToCanvas =
      super.howToAddToCanvas ++ Seq(_.addMouseListener(this))
  }

  trait MouseMotionListener extends Listener {
    override def howToAddToCanvas =
      super.howToAddToCanvas ++ Seq(_.addMouseMotionListener(this))
  }

  . . .

  trait Script extends Listener { . . . }

  object ASpecificScript extends Script with MouseListener with KeyListener with . . .

  . . .

  trait Canvas {
    addMouseListener(listener: MouseListener): Unit
    addMouseMotionListener(listener: MouseMotionListener): Unit
    . . .
  }
```

A disadvantage of this approach is that you have to remember the trick with **super** in each Listener trait. If you forget it in one trait, that trait will shadow rather than augment the `.howToAddToCanvas` of each trait that appears earlier than it in the list of `extends <trait> with <trait> with <trait> with ...`. Other than that (which is very bad!), this approach makes the compiler ensure that the appropriate type of Listener is always passed in the right place.

N.B. I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching as commented by @Archeg, on the types leads to a more concise code, like this,

```
script match {
  case s: MouseListener       => canvas.addMouseListener(s)
  case s: MouseMotionListener => canvas.addMouseMotionListener(s)
  case s: KeyListener         => canvas.addKeyListener(s)
  case s: PaintListener       => addPaint(s)
  case _ => 
}
```

Note each `s: aListener` is an instance of a specific listener, which is used in the canvas method. The last case is introduced for completeness, it matches any other case not matched above and no further action is taken.